# Anypoint mule: CopyOnArraylist in output while writing to file with scatter-gather element

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

The problem statement is to do multiple things parallely and aggregate the response and store it in a file.

link to the mule flow image as in studio: 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr4fs.png)

In this flow, what I was trying to do was to set two constant strings in two branches of scatter and gather and aggregate and store in file. I tried overwriting the payload with a "set payload" with "my response". I am expecting "my response" as the content of the file. But instead the file content is:

¨Ìsr)java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayListx]ü’F´ê√xpwtmsg 1tmsg 2x

I did debug and the payload at File endpoint was "my response". How and why is the collection getting written into file.

Can anyone help me to get it working.
Following is the xml:

```html
<flow name="mule-assignFlow21123">
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="dummyflow" repeatInterval="10000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
            <quartz:event-generator-job/>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather1" >
            <threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1" poolExhaustedAction="RUN"/>
            <processor-chain>
                <set-payload value="msg 1" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </processor-chain>
            <processor-chain>
                <set-payload value="msg 2" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </scatter-gather>
        <set-payload value="my response" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="/Users/premkumar/Desktop" outputPattern="Results.txt" responseTimeout="10000" mimeType="text/plain" doc:name="Save 2 File"/>
    </flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow will automatically determine the `processingStrategy` from the in-flight event which will be async because of the quartz endpoint, so the file endpoint will fire async also.

Instead explicitly set the flow's `processingStrategy` to `synchronous`:

```
<flow name="mule-assignFlow21123" processingStrategy="synchronous">
<quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="dummyflow" repeatInterval="10000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
    <quartz:event-generator-job/>
</quartz:inbound-endpoint>
<scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather1" >
    <threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1" poolExhaustedAction="RUN"/>
    <processor-chain>
        <set-payload value="msg 1" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </processor-chain>
    <processor-chain>
        <set-payload value="msg 2" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </processor-chain>
</scatter-gather>
<set-payload value="my response" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<file:outbound-endpoint path="/Users/premkumar/Desktop" outputPattern="Results.txt" responseTimeout="10000" mimeType="text/plain" doc:name="Save 2 File"/>
```

Comment: it worked. my mule runtime version is 3.7.0 .
When the same flow xml (without processingStrategy explicitly mentioned) was deployed on mule runtime version 3.7.2, it worked without any problem. Does this mean that issue was taken care in the latest version.

The other thing I want clarification is regarding the async, my understanding says that only the initial inbound point in this case will be async, rest of the elements in the flow should be sync. Isn't it? as they are not wrapped with async scope.

Comment: can you give an explanation as to why it works fine in 3.7.2 runtime version without making any changes. Is it because they have corrected in latest version?